# RHEL 4.8 / Sybase 12.5.4 64 bit install error - I have libaio i368 installed I need libaio x86_64 installed

Tags: rhel4, sybase

I am trying to install Sybase ASE 12.5.4 64 bit. I know the machine has a 64 bit processor It is giving me an error during install saying: "error while loading shared libraries: libaio.s0.1"

I run the command:

`rpm -q --qf '%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}  (%{ARCH})\n' libaio`

Which returns:

`libaio-0.3.105-2  (i386)`

I found a src rpm for libaio-0.3.102. I followed the steps to install which included using make. It appeared to install without error. But when I run the rpm -q command again I still only see the i386 version installed.

Not really sure where to go from here. Ideally I would like to find a regular rpm of libaio x86_64 for RHEL 4.8. If I were to find one would I upgrade the package that is already there? Would I remove and install the new one. Or would I install and two separate version of the library?

Comment: I solved my problem by creating a symbolic link from the libaio that I compiled from source to usr/lib64/libaio.so.1.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're actually running 64 bit Linux?  Try checking `uname -m`.

If you have libaio-0.3.105-2 (i386), don't use -0.3.102 (x86_64).  Grab the proper RPM from a CentOS mirror if you don't have access to up2date.

The libraries can coexist.

Edit:  SRPMs are usually `rpmbuild -bb`.  `make` isn't typically required.  Building the SRPM will give you a RPM in a subdirectory of /root (by default) which you must manually install.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

uname -m returns x86_64

I found that out after looking at /usr/lib and usr/lib64

Comment: Go grab the RPM from [here](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/5601946/com/libaio-0.3.105-2.x86_64.rpm.html) and install it as usual with `rpm -Uvh`.

Answer (score 1):

or install package 'libaio.x86_64' which is on install cd. cd can be downloaded from redhat. you can have both versions installed (i386 as well as x86_64)